# Unable to restore list item from recycle bin Sharepoint 2013

Tags: splistitem, restore, delete, recycle-bin

Hello a user deleted a record from a custom list. I went to the recycle bin to restore it but when I try it It shows me with the unexpected error screen and the correlation ID. I'm unable to restore any item deleted from this list or any other list or document library. Restore isn't  working for this site nor other sites since I have tested it with other site collections.This is my ULS Log for that correlation ID:

02/03/2017 08:33:58.23    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium    Name=Request (POST:http://emxdfem0204:80/sites/OS.PMTool.DEV/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx)    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.23    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Authentication Authorization    agb9s    Medium    Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w, ClaimsCount=54    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.23    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium    Site=/sites/OS.PMTool.DEV    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.26    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Files    ak8dj    High    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()     at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.26    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Files    aiv4w    Medium    Spent 0 ms to bind 25144 byte file stream    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.26    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Files    ahjkm    Medium    Spent 0 ms to send 25144 byte file stream    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.26    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Monitoring    b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (GetFileAndMetaInfo). Execution Time=22.7910251163207    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.26    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Monitoring    b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (GetWebPartPageContent). Execution Time=23.0648029288639    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.28    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Database    d0d6    High    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock)  ClientConnectionId:27063ce2-5253-4c6d-9644-78e01263adc3  Error Number:512,State:1,Class:16    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.28    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Database    ad194    High    ExecuteQuery failed with original error 0x80131904    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.28    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Database    afg9p    High    Failed to get output parameter, HR: 0x80131509, Native stack:    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.28    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    8e2s    Medium    Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80131904    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.28    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    aix9j    High    SPRequest.GetRecycleBinItems: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-1538607324-3213881460-940295383-160553, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrWebUrl=http://emxdfem0204/sites/OS.PMTool.DEV    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.28    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    ai1wu    Medium    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904, StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.EnsureContent()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.get_Count()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.FindRowIndex(Guid id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.GetSortedIds(Guid[] ids, SPRecycleBinItemType[]& itemTypes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.ProcessAction(String action, String guidString)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.28    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    8nca    Medium    Application error when access /_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx, Error=Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetRecycleBinItems(String bstrWebUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetRecycleBinItems(String bstrWebUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Database    d0d6    High    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock)  ClientConnectionId:27063ce2-5253-4c6d-9644-78e01263adc3  Error Number:512,State:1,Class:16    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Database    ad194    High    ExecuteQuery failed with original error 0x80131904    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Database    afg9p    High    Failed to get output parameter, HR: 0x80131509, Native stack:    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    8e2s    Medium    Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80131904    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    aix9j    High    SPRequest.GetRecycleBinItems: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-1538607324-3213881460-940295383-160553, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrWebUrl=http://emxdfem0204/sites/OS.PMTool.DEV    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    ai1wu    Medium    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904, StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.EnsureContent()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.get_Count()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.FindRowIndex(Guid id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.GetSortedIds(Guid[] ids, SPRecycleBinItemType[]& itemTypes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.ProcessAction(String action, String guidString)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Runtime    tkau    Unexpected    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetRecycleBinItems(String bstrWebUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetRecycleBinItems(String bstrWebUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    ajlz0    High    Getting Error Message for Exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80131904): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetRecycleBinItems(String bstrWebUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetRecycleBinItems(String bstrWebUrl, Object& pvarItems, UInt32& pdwNumberOfItems)    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.29    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    General    aat87    Monitorable        2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.30    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Micro Trace    uls4    Medium    Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,3 agb9s,27 ak8dj,6 b4ly,0 b4ly,17 d0d6,0 aix9j,0 ai1wu,0 8nca,9 d0d6,0 aix9j,0 ai1wu,0 tkau,0 ajlz0,0 aat87    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

02/03/2017 08:33:58.30    w3wp.exe (0x6070)    0x99FC    SharePoint Foundation    Monitoring    b4ly    Medium    Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://emxdfem0204:80/sites/OS.PMTool.DEV/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx)). Execution Time=72.4323901501448    2369d19d-79cd-7026-1448-387f320c6f13

Answer (score 0):

see if you can connect to SharePoint content database and look at a table called dbo.recyclebin. Its most likely that you will find a data that's stored in the table which has same listID. whenever you try to restore or empty a recycle bin a stored proc RESTORE-SPsite runs behind the scene. and the restore fails if there is a duplicate entry in the recycle bin.
this usually happens when you try to backup a site collection and restore the site collection to a same content database, it assign a same list ID but with different URL.

Comment: Yes I can connect to dbo.recyclebin. Y queried it and I found the records. But How can fix it? This happenes for any site. I created a new site and created a test custom list, I deleted an item from that list and when i try to restore it fails.